# DirectSound: simple pcm playing

Tags: c++, winapi, directsound

I'm playing with DirectSound and trying to play simple random wav data with following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPDIRECTSOUND8 dsound;
    WAVEFORMATEX format;
    const int numchunks = 8;
    LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER dsbuf;
    DSBUFFERDESC buf_format;
    const int chunksize = 1024;
    HRESULT res;
    uint8_t *data1,*data2;
    uint32_t size1,size2;

    memset(&format,0,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));

    format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    format.nChannels  = 1;
    format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    format.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
    format.nBlockAlign = format.nChannels * format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    format.nAvgBytesPerSec = format.nBlockAlign * format.nSamplesPerSec ;   
    format.cbSize = 0;

    assert(DirectSoundCreate8(NULL,&dsound,NULL) == DS_OK);


    assert(dsound->SetCooperativeLevel(GetDesktopWindow(),DSSCL_PRIORITY) == DS_OK);


    memset(&buf_format,0,sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC));
    buf_format.dwSize = sizeof(buf_format);
    buf_format.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_GETCURRENTPOSITION2;
    buf_format.dwFlags |= DSBCAPS_STICKYFOCUS;
    buf_format.dwBufferBytes = numchunks * chunksize;
    buf_format.dwReserved = 0;
    buf_format.lpwfxFormat = &format;


    res = dsound->CreateSoundBuffer(&buf_format,&dsbuf,NULL);
    assert(res == DS_OK );

    srand(time(NULL));

    assert(IDirectSoundBuffer_Lock(dsbuf,0,buf_format.dwBufferBytes,(LPVOID *)&data1,(LPDWORD)&size1,
                            (LPVOID *)&data2,(LPDWORD)&size2,DSBLOCK_ENTIREBUFFER) == DS_OK);

    cout << "got buffer with size "<<size1<<endl;

    for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size1; i ++)
        data1[i] = rand() % 256;

    IDirectSoundBuffer_Unlock(dsbuf,
                                  (LPVOID) data1, (DWORD)size1,
                                  (LPVOID) data2, (DWORD)size2);

    assert(IDirectSoundBuffer_Play(dsbuf,0,0,DSBPLAY_LOOPING) == DS_OK);


    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

but on output i hear only silence. Also there are no error on outputs and my data1 is really some random stuff. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your sound card (or its driver) could be dissing the garbage, you should try generating a sine wave in data1

Comment: Where is your `IDirectSound8::SetCooperativeLevel` call, do you have any?

Comment: i've successfully played random data with WinMM and XAudio2. So i don't think sin-wave will show the problem. Also i'm calling SetCooperativeLevel as you may see in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had somekind of your problem and I fixed your code by setting `buf_format.dwFlags` to

`buf_format.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_CTRLPOSITIONNOTIFY | DSBCAPS_GETCURRENTPOSITION2 |DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS | DSBCAPS_LOCSOFTWARE | DSBCAPS_CTRLPOSITIONNOTIFY | DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME | DSBCAPS_GETCURRENTPOSITION2;`

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem, I have found that simply `DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS` was sufficient to get 'sound' from my code